# Why we can't send ether to ethereum address 0x1 via smart contracts

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ether

With this below solidity code I have tried to send ether to ethereum wallet address **0x1** via smart contract and it becomes failed. But, when I try to send ether to address **0x1** directly from my wallet it becomes success.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Transfer {

    constructor () public payable {
        // Deploy contract with 1000 wei for testing purpose
        require(msg.value == 1000);
    }

    function done() public {
        address(0).transfer(1); // Transaction success
    }

    function fail() public {
        address(1).transfer(1); // Transaction failed
    }

    function send(address account) public {
        account.transfer(1); // Transaction success (except 0x1)
    }

}
```

> Why we can't send ether to address **0x1** via contracts ?

**REFERENCE:**

1. Sending ether directly from my wallet is success
   https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x1fdc3a9d03e23b0838c23b00ff99739b775bf4dd7b5b7f2fa38043056f731cdc
2. done() function is success
   https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xd319c40fcf50bd8188ae039ce9d41830ab795e0f92d611b16efde0bfa1ee82cd
3. fail() function is failed
   https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x0c98eafa0e608cfa66777f1c77267ce9bdf81c6476bdefe2a7615158d17b59ad

---

### UPDATE:

After researching about ethereum **pre-compiled contracts** I have written this below solidity code to send ether to **0x1** address via smart contract and it's working.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Learning {

    constructor () public payable {
        // Deploy contract with 1000 wei for testing purpose
        require(msg.value == 1000);
    }

    function test() public returns (bool) {
        // Set minimum gas limit as 700 to send ether to 0x1
        transfer(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001, 1, 700);
        return true;
    }

    function transfer(address _account, uint _wei, uint _gas) private {
        require(_account.call.value(_wei).gas(_gas)());
    }
}
```

For testing, just deploy contract with **1000 wei** and execute `test()` function. It's working :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have accidentally stumbled upon one of ethereum's lesser known "features". The chain actually has a few precompiled contracts (Appendix E in the yellowpaper), one of which lives at `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001` (the `ecrecover` contract).

Your `fail()` function fails with out of gas due to the fact that the `ecrecover` contract's fallback execution will require more than the `2300 gas` forwarded by the `transfer` method.

The `0x0` address is not a special contract, so a regular transfer call works just fine, as it would with any other address.